# How to start and stop a systemd unit with another?

Tags: systemd, coreos

I am using CoreOS to schedule systemd units with fleet. I have two units (`firehose.service` and `firehose-announce.service`. I am trying to get the `firehose-announce.service` to start and stop along with the `firehose.service`. Here is the unit file for `firehose-announce.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Firehose etcd announcer
BindsTo=firehose@%i.service
After=firehose@%i.service
Requires=firehose@%i.service

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment
TimeoutStartSec=30s
ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c 'sleep 1'
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "port=$(docker inspect -f '{{range $i, $e := .NetworkSettings.Ports }}{{$p := index $e 0}}{{$p.HostPort}}{{end}}' firehose-%i); echo -n \"Adding socket $COREOS_PRIVATE_IPV4:$port/tcp to /firehose/upstream/firehose-%i\"; while netstat -lnt | grep :$port >/dev/null; do etcdctl set /firehose/upstream/firehose-%i $COREOS_PRIVATE_IPV4:$port --ttl 300 >/dev/null; sleep 200; done"
RestartSec=30s
Restart=on-failure

[X-Fleet]
X-ConditionMachineOf=firehose@%i.service
```

I am trying to use `BindsTo` with the notion that start and stop of `firehose.service` will also start or stop `firehose-announce.service`. But this never happens correctly. If `firehose.service` is stopped, then `firehose-announce.service` goes to failed state. But when I start `firehose.service`, the `firehose-announce.service` doesn't start up.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Same problem here. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I seem to have finally stumbled on the correct combination to get this working as desired.

In my `firehose-announce.service` unit I only set a `BindsTo`. The entire unit is:

```
[Unit]
Description=Firehose etcd announcer
BindsTo=firehose@%i.service

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment
TimeoutStartSec=30s
ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c 'sleep 1'
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "port=$(docker inspect -f '{{range $i, $e := .NetworkSettings.Ports }}{{$p := index $e 0}}{{$p.HostPort}}{{end}}' firehose-%i); echo -n \"Adding socket $COREOS_PRIVATE_IPV4:$port/tcp to /firehose/upstream/firehose-%i\"; while netstat -lnt | grep :$port >/dev/null; do etcdctl set /firehose/upstream/firehose-%i $COREOS_PRIVATE_IPV4:$port --ttl 300 >/dev/null; sleep 200; done"
RestartSec=30s
Restart=on-failure

[X-Fleet]
X-ConditionMachineOf=firehose@%i.service
```

This will cause the `firehose-announce.service` unit to stop when `firehose.service` does. Great. But how do we start it up again?

I reverse the dependency to be in my `firehose.service` unit like so:

```
[Unit]
Description=Firehose server
Wants=firehose-announce@%i.service
Before=firehose-announce@%i.service

[Service]
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/docker pull firehose/server
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker rm -f firehose-%i
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run --name firehose-%i -p 7474 --env-file /home/core/firehose.env firehose/server
ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker rm -f firehose-%i
User=core
TimeoutStartSec=5m
TimeoutStopSec=20s
RestartSec=30s
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[X-Fleet]
X-Conflicts=firehose@*.service
```

This is saying that `firehose.service` wants `firehose-announce.service` to start up when it does (but don't fail if `firehose-announce.service` can't start). It also makes sure `firehose.service` starts before `firehose-announce.service`.

I tested this and the units now seem to stop and start together as desired.

Comment: Great, I'll try it.

Comment: Apparently, Wants= means optional.  Requires= is a requirement. BindsTo means if dependancy i.e. firehose-service stops then firehose-announce service is considered stopped too. Sounds like a good thing to me.

Comment: Is it possible to get this behavior without touching firehouse.service?

Comment: I tried this solution, but am running into one problem. I have service A with Requires=B.service and service B with BindsTo=A.service. When A exits abnormally, I see both A and B get restarted. But when A exits with code 0/SUCESS, both remain in stopped state

Comment: ExecStartPre= {dash}'s `-` serve no purpose on the last one and only serve purpose on all but the last ExecStartPre

Comment: @buddy123 use a "drop-in" override.