# Start and stop one systemd unit with another

Tags: linux, systemd

I have two services A.service and B.service. I want B to be stopped when A exits/get killed/is stopped. Also, I want B to get restarted when A gets restarted. I tried out the answer given in
[How to start and stop a systemd unit with another?](https://serverfault.com/questions/622573/how-to-start-and-stop-a-systemd-unit-with-another) and set my files up as follows:-

A.service

```
[Unit]
Description=A
Before=B.service
Requires=B.service
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/share/A
ExecStopPost=/usr/evo/exit_handler.sh %p
Restart=always
StartLimitBurst=3
StartLimitInterval=300
```

B.service

```
[Unit]
Description=B
BindsTo=A.service

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/share/B start
ExecStop=/usr/share/B stop
StartLimitBurst=5
StartLimitInterval=10
Restart=always
```

When I kill A or do a systemctl restart A, I see that B gets restarted. But when A exits with status 0, I don't see B getting restarted. I have enabled systemd debug loggin and I see that the state of A changes to dead but not to auto-restart

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your B unit is using `BindsTo=`, which is meant to track the state of a unit that may *disappear*.

What you want *instead* of this is `PartOf=`, where this service will exactly track the status of the named service. From the [documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.unit.html#PartOf=):

> `PartOf=`
> Configures dependencies similar to `Requires=`, but limited to stopping and restarting of units. When systemd stops or restarts the units listed here, the action is propagated to this unit. Note that this is a one-way dependency — changes to this unit do not affect the listed units.

I don't think this will fix *all* your problems, though. I suspect you haven't carefully enough considered the actual dependencies between your two services, and will need to do some more thinking (and be able to express yourself) before you can make these units do what they need to do.

Comment: Thanks! I will try that out. Could you elaborate on these problems though?

Comment: Think carefully about which service actually depends on the other, how each behaves in the absence of the other, or when the other crashes.

Answer (score 0):

In the `[Unit]` section [`PropagatesReloadTo=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#PropagatesReloadTo=), [`ReloadPropagatedFrom=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#PropagatesReloadTo=), [`PropagatesStopTo=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#PropagatesStopTo=) and [`StopPropagatedFrom=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#PropagatesStopTo=) can be used to define relationships like this.